# Why Does the treatment of an uncaughtexception appear to be happening in the dead thread, in which the exceptional behaviour occurred?

Tags: java, multithreading

I borrowed this from another question:

```
@Slf4j
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    //do some stuff
                    LOG.debug("about to throw a RE from a worker thead");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("purposeful!");
            }

        };
        LOG.debug("in main thead");
        t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                (thread, throwable) -> LOG.debug("in main thread; catching exception from worker. uncaught exception from worker thread: {} from {}",
                        throwable.getMessage(), thread.getName()));
        t.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        LOG.debug("done-main thead");
    }
}
```

If it runs, the following output is produced:

```
10:19:50.249 [main] DEBUG com.foo.services.search.Main - in main thead
10:19:50.258 [Thread-0] DEBUG com.foo.services.search.Main - about to throw a RE from a worker thead
10:19:50.258 [Thread-0] DEBUG com.foo.services.search.Main - in main thread; catching exception from worker. uncaught exception from worker thread: purposeful! from Thread-0
10:20:00.258 [main] DEBUG com.foo.services.search.Main - done-main thead
```

Why, when thread-0 is finished, does the throwable-catching-activity appear to be occurring inside this completed thread?

Comment: Well, as you've already noted (as per your code) there is a uncaught exception handler which is registered for _each_ thread, i.e. exceptions are _not_ thrown across thread boundaries. Thus the thread that throws the exception also handles it, in the uncaught exception handler at the latest. This also makes sense because threads are not linked and can run at different paces, i.e. if you'd not let the main thread sleep for 10 seconds it could already be done before the inner thread even executed a single line - which code would you think catches the exception in such a case?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be explicitly documented in javadocs, but what makes you expect the handler to run in another thread (and for some reason, you seem to expect the handler to run in the thread that called `setUncaughtExceptionHandler`). Why do you expect that?

Comment: Both well reasoned points. It's the last action of a dying thread. Cool. I had been thinking about it all wrong. In my thoughts: the main thread, in which the uncaughtExceptionHandler was set on the thread, would handle the exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doc of JDK, it is stated that this method is only called by the JVM:

```
    /**
     * Dispatch an uncaught exception to the handler. This method is
     * intended to be called only by the JVM.
     */
    private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
        getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
    }
```

Out of curiosity, I found the relevant source code for hotspot: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/thread.cpp

As you can see in the `thread.cpp`, this logic is triggered when `thread` exit:

```
// For any new cleanup additions, please check to see if they need to be applied to
// cleanup_failed_attach_current_thread as well.
void JavaThread::exit(bool destroy_vm, ExitType exit_type) {
  // ........
  if (!destroy_vm) {
    if (uncaught_exception.not_null()) {
      EXCEPTION_MARK;
      // Call method Thread.dispatchUncaughtException().
      Klass* thread_klass = vmClasses::Thread_klass();
  //...
}
```